# Assign route dynamically Node/Express

Tags: node.js, typescript, express, metaprogramming

I need dynamically assign a new route but it for some reason refuses to work.
When I send a request in the Postman it just keeps waiting for a response

The whole picture of what I am doing is the following:

I've got a controller with a decorator on one of its methods

```
@Controller()
export class Test {


    @RESTful({
        endpoint: '/product/test',
        method: 'post',
    })
    async testMe() {

        return {
            type: 'hi'
        }
        
    }


}
```

```
export function RESTful({ endpoint, method, version }: { endpoint: string, version?: string, method: HTTPMethodTypes }) {

    return function (target: any, propertyKey: string, descriptor: PropertyDescriptor): void {
        const originalMethod = descriptor.value

        Reflect.defineMetadata(propertyKey, {
            endpoint,
            method,
            propertyKey,
            version
        }, target)

        return originalMethod
    }
}
```

```
export function Controller() {

    return function (constructor: any) {
        const methods = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(constructor.prototype)
        Container.set(constructor)

        for (let action of methods) {

            const route: RESTfulRoute = Reflect.getMetadata(action, constructor.prototype)

            if (route) {

                const version: string = route.version ? `/${route.version}` : '/v1'

                Container.get(Express).injectRoute((instance: Application) => {
                    instance[route.method](`/api${version}${route.endpoint}`, async () => {
                        return await Reflect.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(constructor, route.propertyKey)
                        // return await constructor.prototype[route.propertyKey](req, res)
                    })
                })
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Is it possible to dynamically set the route in the way?
I mainly use GraphQL but sometimes I need RESTful API too. So, I want to solve this by that decorator

Comment: @HeikoTheißen Of course!!! I knew that's gonna be a silly mistake)) drop it in answers I'll pick it)

Comment: Thanks a lot for being around!) @HeikoTheißen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order for the response to finish, there must be a [`res.end()`](http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#res.end) or [`res.json(...)`](http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#res.json) or similar. But I cannot see that anywhere in your code.